# Failing to Gzip Data in Powershell

Tags: powershell, compression, gzip

i've been trying for a long time to compress data to gzip but i just can't seem to make it work.
This is my Gzip conversion code:

```
function ConvertTo-GzipData {
  [cmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $false)]
    [byte[]]$Data
  )

  Process {
    $output = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new()
    $gzipStream = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GzipStream $output, ([IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Compress)

      $gzipStream.Write($Data, 0, $Data.Length)
      $gzipStream.Close()
    return $output.ToArray()
  }

}
```

And this is the function that uses the gzip compression funtion. 
This function gets a string which goes to $data

> ```
> function Send-Data
> {
>   Param(
>     [string]$evidence_type,
>     [string]$data
>   )
>     $encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
>     $enc_data = $encoding.GetBytes($data)
>     $gzippedData = ConvertTo-GzipData -Data $enc_data
>     write-host $gzippedData
> }
> ```

i get the following error :

> ConvertTo-GzipData : Cannot process argument transformation on
>   parameter 'Data'. Cannot convert the "System.Byte[]" value of type 
>   "System.Byte[]" to type "System.Byte". At line:10 char:45
>   +     $gzippedData = ConvertTo-GzipData -Data $enc_data
>   +                                             ~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-GzipData], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,ConvertTo-GzipData

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to dot-source the `ConvertTo-GzipData` function after changing the parameter type of `$Data` from `[byte]` to `[byte[]]`

Comment: +1 to Mathias' comment -- looks like there may be an old version of the function still in the session memory... try `Remove-Item Function:\ConvertTo-GzipData -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` then reimport the function as you have it above and try again

Comment: i think that was the case @nferrell , i opened a new instance and it worked